# Angular 5 : Load external CSS file - Not allowed to load local resource

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5.2 in my project and new to the angular framework. My component TS file is looking like this:-

```
loadCSSLink(cssPath: string): void {
    const linkElm = document.createElement('link');
    linkElm.rel = 'stylesheet';
    linkElm.href = cssPath;

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(linkElm);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCSSLink('c://Sample//sample-style.css');
    console.log('Link control added');
}
```

I am getting the error in the console saying **"Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C://Sample//sample-style.css".**

Please suggest the code changes. Eventually, when it works with the local CSS file then i will have to load the CSS file from the 
external web resource.

Comment: Why cant you add the styles in your app `src` folder?

Comment: are you using chrome browser?

Comment: Yeh, i am using Chrome. I cannot have these .CSS files in the src folder. They are coming from the external web resource.

Comment: If its coming from external web source, then simply add  that in your `index.html`. Or provide the web url in your method inted of the local path.

Comment: If they are coming from the external web resource then **load it from external web resource** and not from your local folder

Comment: @smnbbrv i am first trying to do with local file. If it works, then i have to use the external web resource.

Comment: you cant downvote answers to improve it. be descriptive on what you want to accomplish. or comments would help

Comment: I did not downvote it. someone else did it.

Comment: @Karan Try my solution. if you cant make it work let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this web server app.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

We use this web server app to test our app locally. for loading local css, images, etc.
It is user friendly and easy to use and install. 
after installing, launch app, navigate to that external css folder.
you would get something like

```
  http://localhost:8089/externalfolder/style.css
```

copy that and paste it to

```
 this.loadCSSLink("http://localhost:8089/externalfolder/style.css");
```

Comment: But how will i make it work for the production site at later stage.  this.loadCSSLink("http://externalweb.com/externalfolder/style.css");

Comment: OR can i specify the production accessible network path where CSS files are present.

Comment: you can directly specify the url to the external web path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, it is because Chrome specifically blocks local file access this way for security reasons.

Check this http://www.chrome-allow-file-access-from-file.com/

this should solve the problem for you.